# PDO insert statement unable to insert into db

Tags: php, pdo

Not sure what is wrong here, but I am unable to do an insert using the below.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "database";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO bloke(question, dte)
    VALUES(:q, :d, )");
$statement->execute(array(
    "q" => "Bob",
    "d" => "19/12/2014"
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In execute method you have to pass the bind param as in query (include colon too)

```
$statement->execute(array(
        ":q" => "Bob",
        ":d" => "19/12/2014"
    ));
```

see example 2 in official documentation [click me!!](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: `print_r($statement->errorInfo());` show the result of this statement please execute beneath the `$statement->execute()` method

Comment: Array ( [0] => 01000 [1] => 1265 [2] => Data truncated for column 'dte' at row 1 )

Comment: I changed the :d => 923847 then there was an insert.  may be change dte from into to varchar in the db?

Comment: post your sql schema script i.e. create table script

Comment: And its a date column means use mysql date see here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bloke` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `questions` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `dte` int(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63930/discussion-between-gvgvgvijayan-and-x10nd).